# TFS build controller change increases build times

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

### Cross-posted on Visual Studios forums at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37a660f8-d576-4c8c-b249-3aec3a5bc7c6/changing-build-controller-increases-build-times?forum=tfsbuild

Hi there!

We use TFS 2013 with TFS2010 build controller and agents (due to Win2003 restrictions) with a combination of on-premise and Cloud-based VM build servers.

Up until last night my older Win2003 server (on-prem VM) was the build controller and also had one build agent on it. This was causing long delays in pushing out XAML updates if it was running a build so I decided to move it to another VM in the cloud. I configured a new server (Win2008R2), installed TFS10 build controller server only(no build agent) and replaced the existing controller during the install. No issues. After that however my build times went from an average of 10 minutes to over an hour....some builds are timing out.

The new cloud VM is fairly beefy and that's the ONLY thing it's configured for. The GET operation is taking the same so I dont think its network latency (this is a private cloud configured for us). GET times before and after average about 20 seconds.

Why else would moving the build controller from a BC/BuildAgent configuration to its own seperate VM increase the build time so much?

If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: please add your build summary, we can then see the times for each piece of the workflow and identify where the bottle neck is

Comment: Also it sounds like communication issues between the servers. Anything in the event log? When on the build agent can you ping/call out to the Controller? What about the other way round.

Comment: Hi guys i can ping to and from the build to the agents. The only error I see on the build controller is below: Error 8/29/2014 2:49:34 AM .NET Runtime Optimization Service 1101 None

Comment: I will post the build log but its huge and nothing looks amiss. The AT/DT and Build Agents are on-premise but the build controller is in our private cloud. Could this cause the delays?

Comment: We might be underestimating the amount of communication going on between the Build Controller and the Build Agent, or it might be a configuration issue (firewall / ports / address / domain resolution) that makes live hard for the controller and the agent to talk to one another.